# Jquery toggle selections on click

Tags: jquery

I have the following code

```
<div class="row equal">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="col-md-4 panel">
            <h2>If you visit a bank do you...</h2>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#"><span>A. </span>Do this.</a>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-12">
                <a href="#" class="last"><span>B. </span>Do that.</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

As you can see there is a question and then two possible answers.  At the moment, all I do is the following

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
    event.preventDefault();
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

The above can probably be handled better but this is something I can work on.  So if an answer is selected, I add the class active which will change the background colour of the selected answer.

This all works fine at the moment, but I was wondering how to make sure only one answer can be selected?  At the moment, I can select both answers which I do not want to allow them to do.

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this one:

```
//Remove all the active from the link from the `row`
$(this).closest('.row').find('a.active').removeClass('active');
//Add active only for this selector, what is an `a` tag.
$(this).addClass('active');
```

Comment: I'd use this suggestion if it were me.  That way you're only removing the class of active on the anchor's with the class ".active" first.  Then setting the active class for the given anchor that you're clicking on.  Plus this code is a bit more readable.

Comment: Thanks, works perfectly.  Just wondering about one thing.  In the code I show, that is one block which contains a question and two possible answers.  What if I have several blocks with questions and answers.  With this code, it removes the active class if I also click an answer in another block.  Would I need to use id's to target each block individually?

Comment: no worries, I could just use .panel instead of .row.  Thanks

Answer (score 2):

You can remove the class `active` from other element on click of anchor:

```
$( "a" ).click(function( event ) {
 event.preventDefault();
 $('.active').not(this).removeClass('active')
 $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Do this in your `.toggleClass()`:

```
$(this).toggleClass(function(){
    return $(this).closest('.panel').find('a.active').not(this).length ? "" : "active";
});
```

or

```js
$('a').click(function() {
  $(this).toggleClass(function() {
    if ($(this).closest('.panel').find('a.active').not(this).length) {
      alert("You can't select other answer.");
      return;
    } else {
      return "active";
    }
  });
  return false;
});
```

```css
.active {
  color: red;
  font-weight: bold;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row equal">
  <div class="col-md-12">
    <div class="col-md-4 panel">
      <h2>If you visit a bank do you...</h2>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#"><span>A. </span>Do this.</a>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-12">
        <a href="#" class="last"><span>B. </span>Do that.</a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```